# Set Delay within ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay

I need a 5 seconds delay before setting success HTML to the div. I have tried below but it doesn't work. Any one has ideas?

```
$("#glyphicon-chevron-left-daily").click(function () {
    var endDate = $("#DailyViewButtonOk1").data("date");
    var previousButtonHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></span>");

    $(function () {
        callAjax();
    });

    function callAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: loadUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            load: "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />",
            data: { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate },

            success: function (response) {
                $("#_DailyViewResults").html(response);
                $("#_DailyViewResults").show();
                setTimeout(callAjax, 5000);
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }
    $(this).html(previousButtonHtml);
});
```

So the code below now works. The problem now id that the original span within button is not restored.

```
$("#glyphicon-chevron-left-daily").click(function () {
    var endDate = $("#DailyViewButtonOk1").data("date");
    var previousButtonHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></span>");
    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate },

        success: function (response) {
            setTimeout(function (response) {
                $("#_DailyViewResults").html(response);
                $("#_DailyViewResults").show();
                $(this).html(previousButtonHtml);
            }, 1000, response);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. If purpose is showing message, why you "setTimeout(callAjax, 5000);" calling same method imside ajax success?

Comment: loadUrl is not specified..

Comment: ignore the loadUrl. It i snot even valid i realise now.

Comment: not necessarily `loadUrl` is not specified, one can define it as a global for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#glyphicon-chevron-left-daily").click(function () {
    var endDate = $("#DailyViewButtonOk1").data("date");
    var previousButtonHtml = $(this).html();
    $(this).html("<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></span>");
    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        load: "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />",
        data: { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate },

        success: function (response) {
            var params = [];
            params['response'] = response;
            params['previousButtonHtml'] = previousButtonHtml;
            params['that'] = that;

            setTimeout(function(params) {
                $("#_DailyViewResults").html(params['response']);
                $("#_DailyViewResults").show();
                $(params['that']).html(params['previousButtonHtml']);
            }, 5000, params);
        },
        error: function () {
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: That works but $(this).html(previousButtonHtml) is actioned without delay. I am setting it to a different icon before ajax post and setting it to original icon after post.

Comment: put it into settimeout function

Comment: Doing that doest replace the icon to original at all. the button code is                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="glyphicon-chevron-left-daily">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    </button>

Comment: @sanjaysharma any other problem?

Comment: Yes...see my edit please ......So the code below now works. The problem now id that the original span within button is not restored.

Comment: I see. Because in settimeout, previousButtonHtml is undefined. So We should pass it into setimeout. I've edited my answer.

Comment: oh, wait a minute, there is another problem, we cannot get this in settimeout too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the case is ajax, which is executing `success` function, has no callAjax in it's context, therefore `callAjax` is exaluated to `undefined`.

```
success: function (response) {
                    $("#_DailyViewResults").html(response);
                    $("#_DailyViewResults").show();
                    console.log('callAjax=', callAjax);
                    setTimeout(callAjax, 5000);
                },
```

You can easily check thing by logging to console value of `callAjax` from ajax's callback.

Solution is to preserve callAjax function within context, like that:

```
//in ajax call's properties object
success: (function(callAjax) { return function (response) {
    $("#_DailyViewResults").html(response);
    $("#_DailyViewResults").show();
    setTimeout(callAjax, 5000);
}})(callAjax),
error: //...
```

Comment: is this in response to original button spannot being replaced ? coz the delay works now but the above doesnt

Comment: what do you mean by "above"? first snippet (with `console.log`) obviously does not work